# Custom button events for Bootstrap modal showing up multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am having the following modal content

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The content in the above modal dialog is default and will be replaced with the content returned from ajax call as shown below.

I have the following javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //This is a external button whose click opens the dialog
    $('#add_user').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    editPost({
        //some data for addition
    },"scripts/edituser.php");

   $('#update_user').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    editPost({
        //some data fro updation
    },"scripts/edituser.php");

}) ;
//editPost is the function which returns the data from server and appends it 
//to dialog and opens it.
var editPost = function(data,url){
   $.ajax({
      "url" : url,
      "type": "POST",
      "data" : data
   }).done(function(response){
        $('#editModal').empty().append(response);
        var modal = #('#editModal').modal("show");
        // The following button actually present in the modal content               returned from ajax.
        modal .on('click','button#mybutton',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //This form is also present in the modal content returned from ajax call
            $form = $("form[name='myform']");
            var formData = $form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                "url" : 'anotherurl',
                "method" : "POST",
                "data" : formData
            }).done(function(serverResponse){
               //Any event written here is triggering multiple times.
            });

   });

};
 // If I try to register any event on the button which is displayed in the modal from ajax call right here (at this place), it is not working
}
```

If I try to register any click event on the button returned from ajax content (which is displayed in modal), it is not getting registered. But if I register any event inside modal content display ajax 'done' callback, it is working fine. What is the problem with this code?

Also, as you can see there are two events from where I am calling editPost method. So If I click add_user and then update_user the events getting multiplied on each click.

Answer (score 0):

there is a space between modal and .on

```
modal .on('click','button#mybutton',function(e){
```

Comment: No use even if I remove the space.

Comment: I guess events are added multiple times on each click of the button that displays modal dialog. But I want to add the event to the modal dialog only once. Hence I tried attaching event outside the 'done' function. But it is now working.